# EF modify entity in a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
// Inside an action result
tp = dbContext.tp.Single(x => ...);

foreach (Sample sample in tp.samples)
{
    if (sample.SampleStatusId == 1)
        changeSamplestatus(sample, 2, now); //change samples to on hold
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();

public void changeSamplestatus(Sample sample, int sampleStatus, DateTime now)
{
    sample.SampleHistory.Add(new SampleHistory
    {
        OldStatus = sample.SampleStatusId,
        NewStatus = sampleStatus,
    });

    sample.SampleStatusId = sampleStatus;
}
```

I have an entity (sample) that I would like to change it status.

I am calling a function to do so, but the entity doesn't get modified (but it is creating a new row in history table with the correct FK).

It doesn't throw any errors when `SaveChanges` is called. It just doesn't modify the entity.

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: The code you wrote will insert samplehistory record . if you want to update the history tabl then you should read that history and then update it . Then you can change the EntityState property to modified to make an update

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
//INSIDE AN ACTION RESULT
var tp = dbContext.tp.SingleOrDefault(x => ...);

if (tp != null)
{
    foreach (Sample sample in tp.samples)
    {
        if (sample.SampleStatusId == 1)
            changeSamplestatus(sample, 2, DateTime.Now); 
    }

    int flag = dbContext.SaveChanges();
    if (flag > 0)
    {
        // update successful
    }
}

public void changeSamplestatus(Sample sample, int sampleStatus, DateTime now)
{
    //sample.SampleHistory.Add(new SampleHistory
    //{
    //    OldStatus = sample.SampleStatusId,
    //    NewStatus = sampleStatus,
    //});
    sample.SampleStatusId = sampleStatus;
}
```

Don't use `Single` for this case, because it would throw exception if no result was found or there were more than 1 result. Use `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: My question was about somthing else entirely.

Comment: @yogevgershon What is your goal?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this . I hope thiw will work . The Idea is to get the history records first in the context and then update the propterties and set state to mofifed . Please try I didnt tested it but it should work.

```
public void changeSamplestatus(Sample sample, int sampleStatus, DateTime now)
  {
           var historyRecordToUpdate = db.SampleHistory.FirstOrDefault(h=>h.id ==   sampleHistoryId )
    if(historyRecordToUpdate  !=null )
   {
      db.Entry(sample).State= EntityState.Modified;
     sample.SampleStatusId = sampleStatus;
 }
}
```